# how to know the collection name form a given mongo repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm writing a service class which for most parts calls a `FieldRepository<Field, String>` for database transactions. We have one specific case where we have to pass a dynamically generate aggregate pipeline, for which I also use `ReactiveMongoTemplate` in the same service class.

Is there a way I can find out the backing collection from the repository instance? so I don't have to hard code collection name to pass in the ReactiveMongoTemplate?

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = {@Autowired})
public class FieldService {
    private final FieldRepository fieldRepository;
    private final SequenceService sequenceService;
    private final EventUtils eventUtils;
    private final ODataMongoTranspiler odataMongoTranspiler;
    private final ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    private String fieldCollectionName = "fields"; // I don't like having to do this
    // something like fieldRepository.getCollecion() would've worked better

    ...

    Flux<Field> someOtherMethod(X param1, Y param2, Z param3) {
        List<AggregationOperation> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();
        // here I build the pipeline based on args, plus a filter that user passes
        // for example /fields?filter="someField eq 10&anotherField < 30"
        // this is why I need the collection name
        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(pipeline), fieldCollectionName, Field.class);
    }
```